# A simple proof of the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality with vectors

Tags: vectors, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I have seen many proofs online, but none of them is as simple as my potentially correct and simple proof. Please let me know if the following is true, and if not where my mistake is.

$$\begin{align*}
|\vec{x} \cdot \vec{y}| &= ||\vec{x}|| \cdot ||\vec{y}|| \cdot \cos(\theta)\\[5pt]
\underbrace{-1 \le \cos(\theta) \le 1}_\le\quad\underbrace{||\vec{x}||}_{\ge0} \cdot \underbrace{||\vec{y}||}_{\ge0} &=||\vec{x}|| \cdot ||\vec{y}||\\[5pt]
\end{align*}$$

Comment: That is not the usual definition of inner product.

Comment: Not sure what usual means. Either it is or it's not, no?

Comment: Ok bottom answer explained what you meant :)

Comment: Please use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) going forward.

Answer (score 4):

Your proof is true for some dot products. It depends on the way you define a dot product. You used the fact that
$$
x \cdot y = ||x|| \times || y|| \times \cos(\theta)
$$
where $\theta$ is the angle between $x$ and $y$,
which is true with the canonical dot product over $\Bbb R^n$. But for a random dot product (positive definite symmetric bilinear form) the existence of such $\theta$ isn't acquired yet. In fact, it's thanks to the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality that we get it.